# Azure File Copy Task in pipeline creating $tf directory

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-file-copy

I have a Azure File Copy Task as a part of my build. Some directory needs to be recursively copied to a blob container. Basically, the "cdn" directory from sources should be copied to the cdn blob container.

So, as "Source" for the task, i specified "$/Website/AzureWebsite/www.die.de/cdn-content/cdn/*"
As "Container Name" i specified "cdn".

The task works: My files do get copied. However, after the copying ends, i also see a directory named "$tf" which has various subdirectories with numbers as names. (0, 1, 2, etc.). All of those contain files named "*.gz" or ".rw".

Where is this coming from and how do i get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/391618/tf-file-is-still-created-in-a-release-delete-all-s.html, the $tf folder is generated when mapping sources for TFVC repository, it's by design. It will create a temp workspace and map the sources first when you queue a build.

If you want to get rid of these, then set the Workspace type to a server workspace, but [lose the advantages of local workspaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx). See: [TFS creates a $tf folder with gigabytes of .gz files. Can I safely delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825021/tfs-creates-a-tf-folder-with-gigabytes-of-gz-files-can-i-safely-delete-it/26678540) for guidance.